# Integration of $1/(x\sqrt{25x^2-1})$

Tags: calculus, integration, radicals

$$\int{\frac{1}{x\sqrt{25x^2-1}}}\,dx$$

Let $x=\frac{1}{5}u$

Now when I substite it and simplify I get

$$\int{\frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}}\, du$$

There is a trig identity which says that this is equal to $$\sec^{-1} u$$

But this is incorrect.  I can't figure this out.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: For one thing, you should have $\dfrac 1 {u\sqrt{u^2-1}}\,du$ rather than $\dfrac 1 {u\sqrt{u^2-1}}\,dx$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Oops.  It was a typo, I actually meant du instead of dx.

Comment: It should be $\displaystyle \int{\frac{5}{u \sqrt{u^2-1}}}du$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{25x^2-1}}=\int\frac{25x}{25x^2\sqrt{25x^2-1}}dx$$

Let $\sqrt{25x^2-1}=u\implies\dfrac{50x\ dx}{2\sqrt{25x^2-1}}=du$ and $25x^2-1=u^2\iff25x^2=u^2+1$

Answer (score 1):

It should be: $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{du}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}} $, which equals to $\sec^{-1} u + C = \sec^{-1} (5x) + C$

Comment: When I differentiate $\sec^{-1}(5x) + C$, I find that this is the incorrect answer as its not equal to the integrand.

Comment: I plugged it into http://www.derivative-calculator.net/#

Comment: It probably is equal but in a different form. Try manipulating the expression. What did you get for the derivative?

Answer (score 1):

If $u=\sec\theta$ the $\sqrt{u^2-1}=\tan\theta$ and $\dfrac{du}u = \tan\theta\,d\theta$, so the integral is $$\int 1\,d\theta = \theta+C = \sec^{-1}u+C.$$

This works for $\theta$ in the first quadrant.  In other quadrants, you need to think about "$\pm$' issues.